# Regex to match card code input

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I write a regex to match strings following these rules?

- 1 letter followed by 4 letters or numbers, then
- 5 letters or numbers, then
- 3 letters or numbers followed by a number and one of the following signs: ! & @ ?

I need to allow input as a 15-character string or as 3 groups of 5 chars separated by one space.

I'm implementing this in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not going to write out the whole regex for you since this is homework, but here are some hints which should help you out:

- Use character classes. `[A-Z]` matches all uppercase. `[a-z]` matches all lowercase. `[0-9]` matches numbers. You can combine them like so `[A-Za-z0-9]`.
- Use quantifiers like `{n}` so `[A-Z]{3}` gives you 3 uppercase letters.
- You can put other characters in character classes. Let's say you wanted to match % or @ or #, you could do `[%@#]` which would match any of those characters.
- Some meta-characters (characters which have special meaning in the context of regular expressions) will need to be escaped like so: `\$` (since `$` matches the end of a line)
- `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the line respectively.
- `\s` matches white-space, but if you sanitize your input, you shouldn't need to use this.
- Flags after the regex do special things. For example in `/[a-z]/i`, the `i` ignores case.

Comment: It's not clear this is homework, that was just some drive-by tag vandal.

Comment: @Roger: even if it is not homework *per se* the OP clearly finds herself *learning* regular expressions and will get more out of a pedagogical response than a finished answer. Or at least that's my view.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm not suggesting a pedagogical answer shouldn't be given; just as for non-homework questions, explaining why is always more valuable.  But answers along the lines of "you don't deserve a complete answer, here's some hints" are mildly offensive (at best).

Comment: @Roger, I wasn't trying to be offensive. I honestly thought it was homework (I looked at the tag). It may have been drive-by-tagging. But I made the answer assuming that it was homework. And based on my assumption, I think it's better to point people towards the right direction rather than just giving them the answer. I wasn't trying to imply that they didn't deserve an answer. I was just trying to help them learn because I (possibly wrongly) assumed that it was homework; this is what I've personally experienced when asking for help with homework questions (outside SO, when I was in school).

Comment: Didn't downvote you or anything, I think you did a decent job outlining various features---and that's the key issue: it's *always* better to point people in the right direction with a solid foundation regardless of whether it's homework or not.  I just don't see why answers should change depending on that factor.  Homework should not be a riddle students are made to **guess** at.

Answer (score 1):

This should be it:

```
/^[a-z][a-z0-9]{4} ?[a-z0-9]{5} ?[a-z0-9]{3}[0-9][!&@?]$/i
```

Feel free to change 0-9 and [0-9] with `\d` if you see fit.
The regex is simple and readable enough. `^` and `$` make sure this is a whole match, so there aren't extra characters before or after the code, and the `/i` flag allows upper or lower case letters.

Comment: The specification does only allow 15 or 17 characters; your regular expression would also allow 16 characters.

Comment: @Gumbo - that is correct, and I was well aware of that. Seems nicer that way. @Stephen - I wish people stopped adding the homework tag for no good reason. Lets see what gets implemented first.

Answer (score 1):

I would start with a [tutorial](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/re.shtml).

Pay attention to the quantifiers (like `{N}`) and character classes (like `[a-zA-Z]`)

Answer (score 0):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{4} ?[a-zA-Z0-9]{5} ?[a-zA-Z0-9]{3}[\!\&\@\?]$
```

Comment: You don’t need to escape these characters inside a character class; `[!&@?]` suffices.